# How to set directory to filechooser.FileSystemView

Tags: java, swing, jtree, jfilechooser

I have a customized JTree that shows file and folders of a directory, currently it only pick the desktop directory. I could not fine any line to modify it. also `fileSystemView` only has getters and not setter.

Here is my working code with default 'desktop' parent directory.

```
public final class MainPanel extends JPanel {
    private MainPanel() {
        super(new BorderLayout());

        final FileSystemView fileSystemView = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();

        DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode();
        final DefaultTreeModel treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(root);
        for (File fileSystemRoot: fileSystemView.getRoots()) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new CheckBoxNode(fileSystemRoot, Status.DESELECTED));
            root.add(node);
            for (File file: fileSystemView.getFiles(fileSystemRoot, true)) {
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    node.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new CheckBoxNode(file, Status.DESELECTED)));
                }
            }
        }
        treeModel.addTreeModelListener(new CheckBoxStatusUpdateListener());

        final JTree tree = new JTree(treeModel) {
            @Override public void updateUI() {
                setCellRenderer(null);
                setCellEditor(null);
                super.updateUI();
                //???#1: JDK 1.6.0 bug??? Nimbus LnF
                setCellRenderer(new FileTreeCellRenderer(fileSystemView));
                setCellEditor(new CheckBoxNodeEditor(fileSystemView));
            }
        };
        tree.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));
        tree.setRootVisible(false);
        tree.addTreeSelectionListener(new FolderSelectionListener(fileSystemView));
        //tree.setCellRenderer(new FileTreeCellRenderer(fileSystemView));
        //tree.setCellEditor(new CheckBoxNodeEditor(fileSystemView));
        tree.setEditable(true);

        tree.expandRow(0);
        //tree.setToggleClickCount(1);

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        add(new JScrollPane(tree));
        add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("test") {
            @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                System.out.println("------------------");
                searchTreeForCheckedNode(tree.getPathForRow(0));
//                 DefaultMutableTreeNode root = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) treeModel.getRoot();
//                 Enumeration e = root.breadthFirstEnumeration();
//                 while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
//                     DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) e.nextElement();
//                     CheckBoxNode check = (CheckBoxNode) node.getUserObject();
//                     if (check != null && check.status == Status.SELECTED) {
//                         System.out.println(check.file.toString());
//                     }
//                 }
            }
        }), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320, 240));
    }
    private static void searchTreeForCheckedNode(TreePath path) {
        Object o = path.getLastPathComponent();
        if (!(o instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode)) {
            return;
        }
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) o;
        o = node.getUserObject();
        if (!(o instanceof CheckBoxNode)) {
            return;
        }
        CheckBoxNode check = (CheckBoxNode) o;
        if (check.status == Status.SELECTED) {
            System.out.println(check.file.toString());
        } else if (check.status == Status.INDETERMINATE && !node.isLeaf() && node.getChildCount() >= 0) {
            Enumeration e = node.children();
            while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
                searchTreeForCheckedNode(path.pathByAddingChild(e.nextElement()));
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String... args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
    public static void createAndShowGUI() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException
               | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FileSystemTreeWithCheckBox");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        //frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new MainPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class TriStateCheckBox extends JCheckBox {
    private Icon currentIcon;
    @Override public void updateUI() {
        currentIcon = getIcon();
        setIcon(null);
        super.updateUI();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                if (currentIcon != null) {
                    setIcon(new IndeterminateIcon());
                }
                setOpaque(false);
            }
        });
    }
}

class IndeterminateIcon implements Icon {
    private static final Color FOREGROUND = new Color(50, 20, 255, 200); //TEST: UIManager.getColor("CheckBox.foreground");
    private static final int SIDE_MARGIN = 4;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 2;
    private final Icon icon = UIManager.getIcon("CheckBox.icon");
    @Override public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        icon.paintIcon(c, g, x, y);
        int w = getIconWidth();
        int h = getIconHeight();
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2.setPaint(FOREGROUND);
        g2.translate(x, y);
        g2.fillRect(SIDE_MARGIN, (h - HEIGHT) / 2, w - SIDE_MARGIN - SIDE_MARGIN, HEIGHT);
        //g2.translate(-x, -y);
        g2.dispose();
    }
    @Override public int getIconWidth() {
        return icon.getIconWidth();
    }
    @Override public int getIconHeight() {
        return icon.getIconHeight();
    }
}

enum Status { SELECTED, DESELECTED, INDETERMINATE }

class CheckBoxNode {
    public final File file;
    public final Status status;
    public CheckBoxNode(File file) {
        this.file = file;
        status = Status.INDETERMINATE;
    }
    public CheckBoxNode(File file, Status status) {
        this.file = file;
        this.status = status;
    }
    @Override public String toString() {
        return file.getName();
    }
}

class FolderSelectionListener implements TreeSelectionListener {
    private final FileSystemView fileSystemView;
    public FolderSelectionListener(FileSystemView fileSystemView) {
        this.fileSystemView = fileSystemView;
    }
    @Override public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
        final JTree tree = (JTree) e.getSource();
        final DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) e.getPath().getLastPathComponent();

        if (!node.isLeaf()) {
            return;
        }
        CheckBoxNode check = (CheckBoxNode) node.getUserObject();
        if (check == null) {
            return;
        }
        final File parent = check.file;
        if (!parent.isDirectory()) {
            return;
        }
        final Status parentStatus = check.status == Status.SELECTED ? Status.SELECTED : Status.DESELECTED;

        final DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel) tree.getModel();
        Task worker = new Task(fileSystemView, parent) {
            @Override protected void process(List<File> chunks) {
                if (!tree.isDisplayable()) {
                    System.out.println("process: DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE");
                    cancel(true);
                    return;
                }
                for (File file: chunks) {
                    model.insertNodeInto(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new CheckBoxNode(file, parentStatus)), node, node.getChildCount());
                    //node.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new CheckBoxNode(file, parentStatus)));
                }
                //model.reload(parent); //= model.nodeStructureChanged(parent);
            }
        };
        worker.execute();
    }
}

class Task extends SwingWorker<String, File> {
    private final FileSystemView fileSystemView;
    private final File parent;
    public Task(FileSystemView fileSystemView, File parent) {
        super();
        this.fileSystemView = fileSystemView;
        this.parent = parent;
    }
    @Override public String doInBackground() {
        File[] children = fileSystemView.getFiles(parent, true);
        for (File child: children) {
            if (child.isDirectory()) {
                publish(child);
            }
        }
        return "done";
    }
}

class FileTreeCellRenderer extends TriStateCheckBox implements TreeCellRenderer {
    private final FileSystemView fileSystemView;
    private final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    private final DefaultTreeCellRenderer renderer = new DefaultTreeCellRenderer();
    public FileTreeCellRenderer(FileSystemView fileSystemView) {
        super();
        String uiName = getUI().getClass().getName();
        if (uiName.contains("Synth") && System.getProperty("java.version").startsWith("1.7.0")) {
            System.out.println("XXX: FocusBorder bug?, JDK 1.7.0, Nimbus start LnF");
            renderer.setBackgroundSelectionColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        }
        this.fileSystemView = fileSystemView;
        panel.setFocusable(false);
        panel.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
        panel.setOpaque(false);
        panel.add(this, BorderLayout.WEST);
        this.setOpaque(false);
    }
    @Override public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
        JLabel l = (JLabel) renderer.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, selected, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);
        l.setFont(tree.getFont());
        if (value instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode) {
            this.setEnabled(tree.isEnabled());
            this.setFont(tree.getFont());
            Object userObject = ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) value).getUserObject();
            if (userObject instanceof CheckBoxNode) {
                CheckBoxNode node = (CheckBoxNode) userObject;
                if (node.status == Status.INDETERMINATE) {
                    setIcon(new IndeterminateIcon());
                } else {
                    setIcon(null);
                }
                setText("");

                File file = (File) node.file;
                l.setIcon(fileSystemView.getSystemIcon(file));
                l.setText(fileSystemView.getSystemDisplayName(file));
                l.setToolTipText(file.getPath());
                setSelected(node.status == Status.SELECTED);
            }
            //panel.add(this, BorderLayout.WEST);
            panel.add(l);
            return panel;
        }
        return l;
    }
    @Override public void updateUI() {
        super.updateUI();
        if (panel != null) {
            //panel.removeAll(); //??? Change to Nimbus LnF, JDK 1.6.0
            panel.updateUI();
            //panel.add(this, BorderLayout.WEST);
        }
        setName("Tree.cellRenderer");
        //???#1: JDK 1.6.0 bug??? @see 1.7.0 DefaultTreeCellRenderer#updateUI()
        //if (System.getProperty("java.version").startsWith("1.6.0")) {
        //    renderer = new DefaultTreeCellRenderer();
        //}
    }
}

class CheckBoxNodeEditor extends TriStateCheckBox implements TreeCellEditor {
    private final FileSystemView fileSystemView;
    private final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    private final DefaultTreeCellRenderer renderer = new DefaultTreeCellRenderer();
    private File file;
    public CheckBoxNodeEditor(FileSystemView fileSystemView) {
        super();
        this.fileSystemView = fileSystemView;
        this.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                stopCellEditing();
            }
        });
        panel.setFocusable(false);
        panel.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
        panel.setOpaque(false);
        panel.add(this, BorderLayout.WEST);
        this.setOpaque(false);
    }
    @Override public Component getTreeCellEditorComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row) {
        //JLabel l = (JLabel) renderer.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, selected, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);
        JLabel l = (JLabel) renderer.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, true, expanded, leaf, row, true);
        l.setFont(tree.getFont());
        setOpaque(false);
        if (value instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode) {
            this.setEnabled(tree.isEnabled());
            this.setFont(tree.getFont());
            Object userObject = ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) value).getUserObject();
            if (userObject instanceof CheckBoxNode) {
                CheckBoxNode node = (CheckBoxNode) userObject;
                if (node.status == Status.INDETERMINATE) {
                    setIcon(new IndeterminateIcon());
                } else {
                    setIcon(null);
                }
                file = node.file;
                l.setIcon(fileSystemView.getSystemIcon(file));
                l.setText(fileSystemView.getSystemDisplayName(file));
                setSelected(node.status == Status.SELECTED);
            }
            //panel.add(this, BorderLayout.WEST);
            panel.add(l);
            return panel;
        }
        return l;
    }
    @Override public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return new CheckBoxNode(file, isSelected() ? Status.SELECTED : Status.DESELECTED);
    }
    @Override public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject e) {
        if (e instanceof MouseEvent && e.getSource() instanceof JTree) {
            MouseEvent me = (MouseEvent) e;
            JTree tree = (JTree) e.getSource();
            TreePath path = tree.getPathForLocation(me.getX(), me.getY());
            Rectangle r = tree.getPathBounds(path);
            if (r == null) {
                return false;
            }
            Dimension d = getPreferredSize();
            r.setSize(new Dimension(d.width, r.height));
            if (r.contains(me.getX(), me.getY())) {
                if (file == null && System.getProperty("java.version").startsWith("1.7.0")) {
                    System.out.println("XXX: Java 7, only on first run\n" + getBounds());
                    setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 0, d.width, r.height));
                }
                //System.out.println(getBounds());
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    @Override public void updateUI() {
        super.updateUI();
        setName("Tree.cellEditor");
        if (panel != null) {
            //panel.removeAll(); //??? Change to Nimbus LnF, JDK 1.6.0
            panel.updateUI();
            //panel.add(this, BorderLayout.WEST);
        }
        //???#1: JDK 1.6.0 bug??? @see 1.7.0 DefaultTreeCellRenderer#updateUI()
        //if (System.getProperty("java.version").startsWith("1.6.0")) {
        //    renderer = new DefaultTreeCellRenderer();
        //}
    }

    //Copied from AbstractCellEditor
//     protected EventListenerList listenerList = new EventListenerList();
//     protected transient ChangeEvent changeEvent;

    @Override public boolean shouldSelectCell(EventObject anEvent) {
        return true;
    }
    @Override public boolean stopCellEditing() {
        fireEditingStopped();
        return true;
    }
    @Override public void cancelCellEditing() {
        fireEditingCanceled();
    }
    @Override public void addCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener l) {
        listenerList.add(CellEditorListener.class, l);
    }
    @Override public void removeCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener l) {
        listenerList.remove(CellEditorListener.class, l);
    }
    public CellEditorListener[] getCellEditorListeners() {
        return listenerList.getListeners(CellEditorListener.class);
    }
    protected void fireEditingStopped() {
        // Guaranteed to return a non-null array
        Object[] listeners = listenerList.getListenerList();
        // Process the listeners last to first, notifying
        // those that are interested in this event
        for (int i = listeners.length - 2; i >= 0; i -= 2) {
            if (listeners[i] == CellEditorListener.class) {
                // Lazily create the event:
                if (changeEvent == null) {
                    changeEvent = new ChangeEvent(this);
                }
                ((CellEditorListener) listeners[i + 1]).editingStopped(changeEvent);
            }
        }
    }
    protected void fireEditingCanceled() {
        // Guaranteed to return a non-null array
        Object[] listeners = listenerList.getListenerList();
        // Process the listeners last to first, notifying
        // those that are interested in this event
        for (int i = listeners.length - 2; i >= 0; i -= 2) {
            if (listeners[i] == CellEditorListener.class) {
                // Lazily create the event:
                if (changeEvent == null) {
                    changeEvent = new ChangeEvent(this);
                }
                ((CellEditorListener) listeners[i + 1]).editingCanceled(changeEvent);
            }
        }
    }
}

class CheckBoxStatusUpdateListener implements TreeModelListener {
    private boolean adjusting;
    @Override public void treeNodesChanged(TreeModelEvent e) {
        if (adjusting) {
            return;
        }
        adjusting = true;
        Object[] children = e.getChildren();
        DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel) e.getSource();

        DefaultMutableTreeNode node;
        CheckBoxNode c; // = (CheckBoxNode) node.getUserObject();
        if (children != null && children.length == 1) {
            node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) children[0];
            c = (CheckBoxNode) node.getUserObject();
            TreePath parent = e.getTreePath();
            DefaultMutableTreeNode n = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) parent.getLastPathComponent();
            while (n != null) {
                updateParentUserObject(n);
                DefaultMutableTreeNode tmp = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) n.getParent();
                if (tmp == null) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    n = tmp;
                }
            }
            model.nodeChanged(n);
        } else {
            node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) model.getRoot();
            c = (CheckBoxNode) node.getUserObject();
        }
        updateAllChildrenUserObject(node, c.status);
        model.nodeChanged(node);
        adjusting = false;
    }
    private void updateParentUserObject(DefaultMutableTreeNode parent) {
        Object userObject = parent.getUserObject();
        if (userObject instanceof CheckBoxNode) {
            File file = ((CheckBoxNode) userObject).file;
            int selectedCount = 0;
            int indeterminateCount = 0;
            Enumeration children = parent.children();
            while (children.hasMoreElements()) {
                DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) children.nextElement();
                CheckBoxNode check = (CheckBoxNode) node.getUserObject();
                if (check.status == Status.INDETERMINATE) {
                    indeterminateCount++;
                    break;
                }
                if (check.status == Status.SELECTED) {
                    selectedCount++;
                }
            }
            if (indeterminateCount > 0) {
                parent.setUserObject(new CheckBoxNode(file));
            } else if (selectedCount == 0) {
                parent.setUserObject(new CheckBoxNode(file, Status.DESELECTED));
            } else if (selectedCount == parent.getChildCount()) {
                parent.setUserObject(new CheckBoxNode(file, Status.SELECTED));
            } else {
                parent.setUserObject(new CheckBoxNode(file));
            }
        }
    }
    private void updateAllChildrenUserObject(DefaultMutableTreeNode root, Status status) {
        Enumeration breadth = root.breadthFirstEnumeration();
        while (breadth.hasMoreElements()) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) breadth.nextElement();
            if (root.equals(node)) {
                continue;
            }
            CheckBoxNode check = (CheckBoxNode) node.getUserObject();
            node.setUserObject(new CheckBoxNode(check.file, status));
        }
    }
    @Override public void treeNodesInserted(TreeModelEvent e)    { /* not needed */ }
    @Override public void treeNodesRemoved(TreeModelEvent e)     { /* not needed */ }
    @Override public void treeStructureChanged(TreeModelEvent e) { /* not needed */ }
}
```

Any idea to change its directory ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Dan. In general you should try to avoid posting a wall of code, especially when most of it is unrelated to your problem. It never actually says "desktop" anywhere in that code, is it possible that the file lives on the desktop and it's just defaulting to its current directory?

Comment: @genisage thanks for you advice. actually I tried to make my code shorter but i raised a lot of errors so I thought maybe I better to put the whole class so if anyone try it, they will see the same error as me. but sure I will keep that in mind. And no it is not located in the desktop..

Answer (score 3):

- Use a `File` instead of `FileSystemView` to define the root.
- Use `File#listFiles` to list the files within a specified directory instead of `FileSystemView#getFiles`

Something like...

```
File rootPath = new File(".");

DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode();
final DefaultTreeModel treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(root);
DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new CheckBoxNode(rootPath, Status.DESELECTED));
root.add(node);
for (File file : rootPath.listFiles()) {
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        node.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new CheckBoxNode(file, Status.DESELECTED)));
    }
}
```

for example.

Take a look at [`java.io.File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks for your solution, however changing it to File, brings other errors such as `setCellRenderer(new FileTreeCellRenderer(rootPath));` Incompatible type... Isn't there any way to keep it with FileSystemView but changing the directory ?

Comment: The `FileTreeCellRenderer` is using a instance of `FileSystemView` to make determinations about the icon to  use for a given `File` object.  You can remove the parameter from the constructor and simply use `this.fileSystemView = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();` to get an instance for the renderer to use